# Call parent method in JavaScript class but stll have access to prototype methods inside object instance?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, extending

Is it possible to call parent method in JavaScript class but to still have access to prototype methods from parent and child class. Here is code example:

```
var Base = function() {

  this.baseMethod = function(){
    return 'baseMethod';
  };

  this.baseInitMethod = function() {
    return 'baseInitMethod';
  }
}


Base.prototype.basePrototypeMethod = function() {
  return "basePrototypeMethod";
};


var Specific = function() {

  Base.call(this);

  this.baseInitMethod = function() {
    // call baseInitMethod from Base class
  }

  this.specificMethod = function(){
    return 'specificMethod';
  }

  this.specificInitMethod = function() {

    return this.basePrototypeMethod();
  }
}


Specific.prototype.specificPrototypeMethod = function() {
  return 'specificPrototypeMethod' + '-' + this.baseInitMethod();
}


for(var p in Base.prototype) {
   Specific.prototype[p] = Base.prototype[p]
}


var s = new Specific();


console.log(s.baseMethod());

console.log(s.baseInitMethod());

console.log(s.basePrototypeMethod());

console.log(s.specificMethod());

console.log(s.specificInitMethod());

console.log(s.specificPrototypeMethod());
```

I want to call baseInitMethod in Base class from baseInitMethod method inside Specific class but so that all function calls from above still works. Is that possible?

Comment: Surely what you want breaks the convention of inheritance? If you want to share a method, create a third class that can be used by both.

Comment: Can you give a example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Specific.prototype` object should *inherit* from the `Base.prototype` object. Currently you're copying over all its properties to the object with this code:

> ```
> for(var p in Base.prototype) {
>    Specific.prototype[p] = Base.prototype[p]
> }
> ```

But you should actually use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to establish a real *prototype chain*:

```
Specific.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);

Specific.prototype.specificPrototypeMethod = function() {
  return 'specificPrototypeMethod' + '-' + this.baseInitMethod();
}
```

---

> I want to call baseInitMethod in Base class from baseInitMethod method inside Specific class

Yes. In your `Specific` constructor, you first need get `Base`'s `baseInitMethod` instance method, before you overwrite the property of the instance:

```
function Specific() {
    Base.call(this);

    var parentInitMethod = this.baseInitMethod;
    this.baseInitMethod = function() {
        // call baseInitMethod from Base class:
        parentInitMethod.call(this /*, arguments…*/); 
    }

    …
}
```

> so that all function calls from above still works.

I'm not sure what you mean by that exactly. The `specificPrototypeMethod` will always call the `baseInitMethod` of the current instance, which would be `Specific`'s overwritten one not the original that was defined in `Base`.

Comment: Ohhhh man I feel so stupid :) Answer is so simple I just needed to create reference to parent method before overriding that method in Specific class. Thanks a million. Now I understand why you have 106K rep. You are a ninja :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do:

```
var Base = function () {
};
Base.prototype.baseMethod = function () {
    return 'baseMethod';
};
Base.prototype.baseInitMethod = function () {
    return 'baseInitMethod';
};
Base.prototype.basePrototypeMethod = function () {
    return "basePrototypeMethod";
};


var Specific = function () {
    Base.apply(this, arguments);
};
Specific.prototype.baseInitMethod = function () {
    Base.prototype.baseInitMethod.apply(this,arguments);
};

Specific.prototype.specificMethod = function () {
    return 'specificMethod';
};

Specific.prototype.specificInitMethod = function () {
    var basePrototypeMethodCallResult = Base.prototype.basePrototypeMethod.apply(this,arguments);

};
```

Comment: I know for this. But I do not want all my methods to be in prototype because when you say new Specific() all methods that are inside constructor are recreated again but ones that are in prototype are not recreated again when you say new Specific().

Comment: Exactly. And if you want some method to be used out of the Base, you have to define it inside it's prototype. Otherwise, it's just defined in scope of instance of your Base class.

Comment: btw: I see no problem that methods are not being recreated. Because they are still accessible via "this" instance. Also - isn't it good that things that are not necessary for recreation, are not being recreated during JS runtime? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the `baseInitMethod` of `Base` inside `Specific`, with `Specific`'s definition, so why would you ever want to call the Base version? If you simply remove the overwrite of the function you should call the Base definition:

```
var Base = function() {

  this.baseMethod = function(){
    return 'baseMethod';
  };

  this.baseInitMethod = function() {
    return 'baseInitMethod';
  }
}


Base.prototype.basePrototypeMethod = function() {
  return "basePrototypeMethod";
};


var Specific = function() {

  Base.call(this);

  this.baseInitMethod(); // calls the Base definition only

  this.specificMethod = function(){
    return 'specificMethod';
  }

  this.specificInitMethod = function() {

    return this.basePrototypeMethod();
  }
}
```

Comment: I can not do that because the baseInitMethod is called like public method outside so I need to have it like definition.

Comment: Ok thats fine but you should consider avoiding this over-engineered approach as it is convoluted and almost certainly unnecessary. The answer you marked as correct indicated exactly what I was saying.

Answer (score 0):

One might argue "Why always trying to mimic 'classical' behaviour and fuss with `call` and `apply` instead of embracing the prototype delegation pattern instead?"

Here is what I would code :

```
var Base = {

    baseVariable1: "baseValue1",

    baseVariable2: "baseValue2",

    baseMethod: function () {
        return 'baseMethod';
    },

    baseInitMethod: function () {
        return 'baseInitMethod';
    }
}

var Specific = Object.create(Base);

Specific.variable1 = "value1";

Specific.variable2 = "value2";

Specific.specificInitMethod = function () {
    return 'specificInitMethod' + '-' + this.baseInitMethod();
}

Specific.specificMethod = function () {
    return 'specificMethod' + '-' + this.baseInitMethod();
}

var s = Object.create(Specific);

console.log(s.baseInitMethod());

console.log(s.baseVariable1);

console.log(s.baseVariable2);

console.log(s.variable1);

console.log(s.variable2);

console.log(s.baseMethod());

console.log(s.specificInitMethod());

console.log(s.specificMethod());
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is that I can not have variables inside Base class and I need variables.

Comment: Of course you can, see my edited answer. And there is no class in JS. (I think, even with ES6 and the `class` and `super` keywords, it will be just keywords to hide the real prototypal nature of JS).
`Base` is an object. In my case, it is a plain object, so you can add properties, that can point to functions, primitives, or plain objects. In yours, it is a function, but still an object, since functions are objects in JS, certainly not a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parentable {
  get parent() {
    return this.__proto__.__proto__;
  }
} 
class A extends Parentable { 
  say() { 
    console.log('Hello from A'); 
  } 
}
class B extends A {
  say() {
   console.log('Im not A, I am B! But A send you a message:');
   this.parent.say();
  }
}
(new B()).say();
```